# apache 2.4 on fresh fedora: AH01630: client denied by server configuration

Tags: apache

I've seen hudreds of questions like this and most of them end up in changing the syntax to latest Apache version or messing up with .htaccess. But not in my case since I used fresh F23 install and never played with erarlier Apache versions. I'm trying to set up a simple virtual host that binds to one of my IP's. Here is what I put in /etc/httpd/conf.d/internal.conf

```
Listen 10.10.1.177:80
<VirtualHost 10.10.1.177:80>
        DocumentRoot "/home/www"
        DirectoryIndex index.html
        ServerName internal:80
        <Directory “/home/www“>
                Options All Indexes FollowSymLinks
                Options +Indexes
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
        LogLevel debug
        ErrorLogFormat "%{cu}t %M"
        ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/internal-error.log
        CustomLog /var/log/httpd/internal-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

When I try:

```
curl http://10.10.1.17
```

From other host in that network, first 403 page appears and get redirected to default fedora-apache page. This entries entries gets into error log:

```
2016-04-21 22:45:50.610696 AH01626: authorization result of Require all denied: denied
2016-04-21 22:45:50.610724 AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: denied
2016-04-21 22:45:50.610729 AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/www/
2016-04-21 22:45:50.610763 AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
2016-04-21 22:45:50.610771 AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
```

I just want this virtual server to serve anything that I put to /home/www. What am I missing?

I changed main httpd.conf file to bind to my other network interface. 
I have "greped" all *.conf files for "deny|denied"  statements and found only default "Require all denied" for "/" directory and .ht* files in main config.

Answer (score 1):

There is a `LocationMatch` directive in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/welcome.conf` that is causing this behavior:

```
<LocationMatch "^/+$">
    Options -Indexes
    ErrorDocument 403 /.noindex.html
</LocationMatch>
```

Comment out the comments of that file (or empty out that file), but
*do not* remove that file, because a subsequent upgrade of the `httpd`
package will then bring it back.  It will not be overwritten if you
have modified it locally.

Comment: Hi, Helped a bit. Thanks. But now I see 403 page immediately. And log contains only first three entries I mentioned im my original post. So stil AH01630 message. I get the same behavior when I append "index.html" to my url or not.